# "As if you have your teacher with you"

Tags: tense, subjunctives

I was running across this advertisement for an English language school on the subway this morning:

> English fit for travel, as if you have your teacher with you.

This sounds somehow wrong to me. Shouldn't the subjunctive use the past form of *have* in this case, as in 'As if you **had** your teacher with you'?

Comment: Yes.  Give that school an F in English.

Comment: Well, it's one of the largest language schools around, so I'm a little flabbergasted how they could let such a mistake slip.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Probably because the person designing the advert didn't attend that school? ^_^

Comment: Seems you are not the only one riding the subway: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259233/is-this-advertisement-for-an-english-language-course-properly-worded

Comment: Well the English subjunctive doesn't exist, so no!

Comment: @curiousdannii: It doesn't? That's a new one. So when we say: "I prefer he come tomorrow" how do you justify knocking the -s off the 3rd person form "comes"? What do they call it these days?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The commercial probably meant "had" here. For the situation would be one where the teacher is NOT there with you. The version with "have" has an open-type of interpretation: the speaker has no opinion as to whether or not the teacher is there next to you. The "had" has a modal remote type of interpretation, where the speaker does have an opinion, and it is that the teacher most likely is not there next to you. The past-tense of a verb is often used to show that modal remoteness. (reference: H&P *CGEL*, page 1152-3) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect example of something that is grammatically correct, yet highly unidiomatic. In other words, a native would never word it like this. 
Here are some options that I would personally prefer as a native:

> **English for travel:** It's like traveling with your teacher.
>
> **English for tourists:** It's like having your teacher as a tour
>   guide.
>
> **English for travel:** It's like taking your teacher on the road.

(*I don't really like any of these either - the whole premise seems corny to me, but they're a lot more palatable than the original to my ear at least*).

Comment: “English for tourists—like having your teacher in your back pocket!”

Answer (score 2):

It is grammatically *incorrect*, according to standard English. If I were in charge of that school (but I am not, so I wrote 'were' just then) I would fire the folks who came up with that setence.

Whether one calls it the subjunctive or irrealis is another thing. English does not have a lot of things that Latin has, or had.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. I had to think about it for a while! AmE native, btw.

"As if you **had** your teacher with you" is *definitely* grammatically correct and sounds natural when spoken. If you're erring on the side of caution, certainly go with the "had" version.

If we venture off the grammatically correct path and wander a bit into the forest of sounds-okay-when-spoken-but-maybe-don't-say-it-to-a-pedantic-grammarian-or-put-it-in-a-term-paper, the "have" version might be acceptable as well. It somewhat accents the present-tense aspect of the phrase. It might connote the feeling "this course is so good it'll feel like your teacher is with you all the time, very much in the present".

Note that this feeling is by no means a hard and fast rule and different English speakers, especially the purists among us, might beg strongly to differ.  However, in spoken American English, many good speakers might not bat an eye at the "have" version. Whether the English language company that wrote the ad put this much thought behind it or not is another question entirely.